# Retrieve all collection from document from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve all albums from artist, but i can't do this.
I've got a structure in the Cloud Firestore:

Artists -> Artist Name -> Albums of Artist Name -> Songs.

I've received all songs from album by the code:

```
Future getDocId() async {
     await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('artist').get().then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("artist")
            .doc("Artist1").collection("ArtistsAlbum").get().then((value){
                  value.docs.forEach((element) {
                     docIDs.add(element.id);
                  },
                  );
                  setState(() {});
            });
          }),
        );
```

Code like

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('artist').doc("Rammstein").get();
```

Doesn't work.

Is it possible to receive that data? Or i need to remade my structure like:
Artist1>Albums->Songs
Artist2->Albums->Songs

Comment: Do you have a collection named `ArtistsAlbum` under the `Artist1` document?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have used the album name as the name of the collection, which is not great. There is no way to get a list of all collections at a path from the client-side SDKs of Firestore, so you should only use collection names that you can know from elsewhere, e.g. like the hardcoded `Artist` name, or because you store them somewhere else.

So you main options are to:

- Also store the album names in the artist's document, so that you can read them from there and then access the subcollections based on that.
- Use a more nested structure with hard-coded collections names, like `Artists` > `$artistName` > `Albums` > `$albumName` > `Songs` > `$songName`. In this structure `Artists`, `Albums` and `Songs` are all hard-coded strings, while the others (with a `$` prefix) are dynamic and determined by your code.